# MERGE with UPDATE and COMMIT

Tags: merge, db2, commit

I have one shell script to run a SQL file when we need to prompt it for commit or rollback in DB2. The problem I am facing is with a `MERGE` statement. If the SQL script has a `MERGE` with update statement, the changes won't be reflected in the table until we commit. But if I have a simple `UPDATE` statement, even without committing it I can see the changes in the data using the `"with ur"` option. And if the script having `MERGE` with update has a `COMMIT` just after `MERGE` we cannot roll back the changes as they are already committed. Can somebody tell if `COMMIT` is mandatory after executing `MERGE` statement to see the changes?

Answer (score 1):

The `MERGE` statement in SQL is no different than `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` when it comes to isolating uncommitted changes from other connections. The connection that executed the DML can always see its own changes before they are committed. To view uncommitted changes that were made by another connection ("dirty read"), specify uncommitted read isolation by adding the `WITH UR` qualifier to the end of the `SELECT` statement.

As for auto-commit, it can be disabled in the DB2 CLP by specifying the `-c-` option for every statement in the unit of work:

```
db2 -c- " UPDATE employee SET salary = 200000 WHERE empno= '000010' "
db2 -c- " SELECT salary FROM employee WHERE empno = '000010' "
db2 -c- " ROLLBACK "
db2 -c- " SELECT salary FROM employee WHERE empno = '000010' "
```